# opening php file and i get do you want to open or save file

Tags: php, apache, file-io, module

Recently I configured `Apache 2.2` server to run `PHP` and have configured to load `PHP 5` as a module. I am able to start Apache  with no problems but when I try to run PHP files it pops up would you like to open or save file?

Running on `Windows XP SP3`

`Internet Explorer` browser but not related

Simply trying to open it as a file not as my `index.php` and haven't set Apache to look for that as my `index`. If it helps I think my issue might be here:

```
;AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
;AddType application/x-httpd-php .php5
;AddType application/x-httpd-php .phtml
```

I tried to modify in my Apache conf file `addtype` and `addhandler` but no change and apache still starts both ways.

I tried putting these inside the mime configuration part and outside of it same both ways but not sure where in doc that should go my `loadmodule` part is also entered.

Im not sure but the only other place i could see being an issue would be in my php.ini file to which i have made no modifications.

Can someone point me in the right direction? What I am missing here?

Comment: Have you deleted the `;` at the begin of `AddType`?

Answer (score 0):

Edit `httpd.conf` and add (or remove the `;` at the begin of line):

```
# PHP 5.x module
LoadModule php5_module  modules/libphp5.so
AddHandler php5-script  .php 

# Add index.php to your DirectoryIndex line:
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

AddType text/html   .php

# PHP Syntax Coloring
# (optional but useful for reading PHP source for debugging):
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source phps
```

I don't know, but I think you need to restart the Apache.

From http://dan.drydog.com/apache2php.html (step 11)